# With 'kotlin-kapt' plugin, Android Studio doesnt provide specific errors about Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt

I use Kotlin with Dagger 2. The problem is, when I make mistake while implementing Dagger (e.g., miss `@Inject` for class constractor), IDE doesnt show specifically where mistake is. Insead compiler error is always the same:

> `Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. 
>   Internal compiler error. See log for more details`

Class with a deliberate mistake (commented @Inject):

```
class LoginPresenter //@Inject
constructor(private val request: LoginRequest)
```

Project build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kravets_a.kotlinanddagger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10"

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: You can find the error in the gradle log. In Android Studio, in the bottom right, click at `Gradle Console`. There it will show the errors.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak's answer is, apparently, the best there is for now.  It appears that AndroidStudio doesn't handle `kapt` errors yet.  Cross your fingers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`. And when error occurs, you can see it in Android Studio => on the bottom right => at Gradle Console.

*Thanks to David Medenjak comment.*

**Option 2**

Substitute `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` with `kapt { generateStubs = true }`

Compilation fails with expected result:

> [com.example.kravets_a.kotlinanddagger.logic.MainActivityComponent.inject(com.example.kotlinanddagger.MainActivity)] com.example.kotlinanddagger.logic.LoginPresenter cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.

Tutorials like [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/setup-dagger-2-on-kotlin-project-d48d28dcc89e), [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-dagger2-with-kotlin-72af5f066cc4) or [that](https://antonioleiva.com/dagger-android-kotlin/) says that `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` can be used instead of `kapt { generateStubs = true }`. But in that case Android Studio does not provide specific compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add this to your module's build.gradle:

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

Comment: i've tried this recently, as per the official recommendation on kapt, but it's still failing. i.e. `NonExistentClass` is still being added